# Python pywinauto typekeys not working with ALT+N

Tags: python-3.x, pywinauto

Hi i'm trying to automate some program installations, since i'm wring with python i chose pywinauto for this task.
But i'm having issues sending keys to a program, i can open notepad and type stuff, but if i try to type ALT+N when starting an installation (EasyBCD for example) it doesn't responde to the key, while it should press the Next button.

```
import pywinauto
import time

app = pywinauto.Application()
app.window_(title_re='.*EasyBCD.*').SetFocus()
time.sleep(3)
app.window_(title_re='.*EasyBCD.*').TypeKeys('%n')
```

Update:
It seems it was a problem with my PC, maybe the antivirus or some domain rules, but when i ran the code on a different pc, with no antivirus and not connected to the domain everything worked, both Typekeys and ".NextButton.Wait('enabled').Click()"

Comment: The issue seems very specific to your app. Try `TypeKeys('%n', set_foreground=False)`. If it doesn't help I have no another idea.

Comment: `app.window_(title_re='.*EasyBCD.*').NextButton.Wait('enabled').Click()` or `ClickInput()` looks better to me. But the issue with `TypeKeys` is interesting in itself.